# method toequal() with protractor failed

Tags: protractor

I have a problem with protractor. This is my code :

```
var NewSimulationPage = function () {
    this.errormsg = element(by.xpath("//div[@class='errormsg']"));
}

describe('language ', function () {
    it("Creation d'un nouveau Previndi ", function func() {        
    //nouvelle tarification
    oNewSimulationPage = new NewSimulationPage();
    oNewSimulationPage.nextTaskClick();
    expect(oNewSimulationPage.errormsg.getText()).toEqual("La saisie est incomplète");
    });
});
```

In the HTML code I have this:

```
<div class="errormsg" style="display: block;">La saisie est incomplète</div>
```

The value of the `oNewSimulationPage.errormsg.getText()` is "La saisie est incomplète", but when I run the test with protractor, I have an error message: "Expected 'La saisie est incomplète' to equal 'La saisie est incompl?te'."

Why does protractor replace the character 'è' by the charachter '?' ?

Comment: Try to save your test files with UTF8, check for your editor's prefences. Also ensure the webpage is UTF8

Comment: thx for your response. I have converted my spec files into UTF-8 encoding and it works !!!

Comment: Awesome! added as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

- Save your test files with UTF8 encoding (check for your files editor's preferences)
- Ensure the webpage is UTF8.